# How to enable field data in elasticsearch

Tags: c#, .net, elasticsearch

I'm trying to enable field data in elasticsearch, but I'm still gettting the same error.
Can anyone tell me what I'm missing?

**.NET Code**

```
var resByApp = client.Search<ApiCall>(s => s.Aggregations(a => a
                    .Filter("my_filter", f => f
                          .Filter(fd => fd
                               .DateRange(r => r
                                   .GreaterThan(DateTime.UtcNow.ToBeginOfDay().AddDays(-DefaultDaysRange))
                                   .Field(p => p.CreatedDate)
                               )
                               &&
                               fd.Term(t => t.ServiceId, serviceId)
                           )
                    .Aggregations(ag => ag
                              .Terms("app_agg", st => st
                                  .Field(af => af.AppId))
                              )
                          )));
```

**DebugInformation:**

```
Invalid NEST response built from a unsuccessful low level call on POST: /abc_apicalls/apicall/_search
# Audit trail of this API call:
 - [1] BadResponse: Node: http://localhost:9200/ Took: 00:00:00.0459990
# ServerError: ServerError: 400Type: search_phase_execution_exception Reason: "all shards failed" CausedBy: "Type: illegal_argument_exception Reason: "Fielddata is disabled on text fields by default. Set fielddata=true on [appId] in order to load fielddata in memory by uninverting the inverted index. Note that this can however use significant memory.""
# OriginalException: System.Net.WebException: The remote server returned an error: (400) Bad Request.
   at System.Net.HttpWebRequest.GetResponse()
   at Elasticsearch.Net.HttpConnection.Request[TReturn](RequestData requestData) in C:\Users\russc\source\git\elasticsearch-net-5.x\src\Elasticsearch.Net\Connection\HttpConnection.cs:line 164
# Request:
{"aggs":{"my_filter":{"filter":{"bool":{"must":[{"range":{"createdDate":{"gt":"2017-03-26T00:00:00"}}},{"term":{"serviceId":{"value":2}}}]}},"aggs":{"app_agg":{"terms":{"field":"appId"}}}}}}
# Response:
{"error":{"root_cause":[{"type":"illegal_argument_exception","reason":"Fielddata is disabled on text fields by default. Set fielddata=true on [appId] in order to load fielddata in memory by uninverting the inverted index. Note that this can however use significant memory."}],"type":"search_phase_execution_exception","reason":"all shards failed","phase":"query","grouped":true,"failed_shards":[{"shard":0,"index":"abc_apicalls","node":"oYXnz0dhTZ6Bs5ZpspH1hg","reason":{"type":"illegal_argument_exception","reason":"Fielddata is disabled on text fields by default. Set fielddata=true on [appId] in order to load fielddata in memory by uninverting the inverted index. Note that this can however use significant memory."}}],"caused_by":{"type":"illegal_argument_exception","reason":"Fielddata is disabled on text fields by default. Set fielddata=true on [appId] in order to load fielddata in memory by uninverting the inverted index. Note that this can however use significant memory."}},"status":400}
```

**What I tried:**

```
PUT abc_apicalls/apicall/text
{
  "properties": {
    "appId": { 
      "type":     "text",
      "fielddata": true
    }
  }
}
```

**This is the results for `GET abc_apicalls`**

```
{
  "abc_apicalls": {
    "aliases": {},
    "mappings": {
      "apicall": {
        "properties": {
          "appId": {
            "type": "text",
            "fields": {
              "keyword": {
                "type": "keyword",
                "ignore_above": 256
              }
            }
          },
          "properties": {
            "properties": {
              "appId": {
                "properties": {
                  "fielddata": {
                    "type": "boolean"
                  },
                  "type": {
                    "type": "text",
                    "fields": {
                      "keyword": {
                        "type": "keyword",
                        "ignore_above": 256
                      }
                    }
                  }
                }
              }
            }
          },
    ...
  }
}
```

Resources: https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/fielddata.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The type is wrong, this is the proper way to enable a field data

```
PUT abc_apicalls/_mapping/apicall
{
   "apicall": {
      "properties": {
        "appId": {
          "type": "text",
          "fielddata": true
        }
      }
   }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I using Nest 5.4 and do this put mapping by following code:

```
_client.Map<AccountDoc>(m => m.Index("Your_Index_Name").Properties(p =>
            p.Text(t => t.Name(n => n.Your_Field_Name).Fielddata(true))));
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow and thanks for trying to help. However, your answer could be improved by using markdown formatting and by adding an explanation. Code-only answers are not very much loved here. Please take the [tour] for more information on this.

Comment: I can't find `.FieldData` in the latest version of Nest!
Was it moved somewhere else?

Comment: Doesn't seem to make any difference for me, I still get the same error even after doing this...